# ffserver - invalid codec name libvpx

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, ffserver

I have the following configuration of ffserver.conf:

```
Port 8090                      # Port to bind the server to
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 10000             # Maximum bandwidth per client
                               # set this high enough to exceed stream bitrate
CustomLog -
NoDaemon                       # Remove this if you want FFserver to daemonize after start

<Feed feed1.ffm>               # This is the input feed where FFmpeg will send
   File ./feed1.ffm            # video stream.
   FileMaxSize 1G              # Maximum file size for buffering video
   ACL allow 127.0.0.1         # Allowed IPs
</Feed>

<Stream test.webm>              # Output stream URL definition
   Feed feed1.ffm              # Feed from which to receive video
   Format webm

   # Audio settings
   AudioCodec vorbis
   AudioBitRate 64             # Audio bitrate

   # Video settings
   VideoCodec libvpx
   VideoSize 720x576           # Video resolution
   VideoFrameRate 25           # Video FPS
   AVOptionVideo flags +global_header  # Parameters passed to encoder
                                       # (same as ffmpeg command-line parameters)
   AVOptionVideo cpu-used 0
   AVOptionVideo qmin 10
   AVOptionVideo qmax 42
   AVOptionVideo quality good
   AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
   PreRoll 15
   StartSendOnKey
   VideoBitRate 400            # Video bitrate
</Stream>

<Stream status.html>            # Server status URL
   Format status
   # Only allow local people to get the status
   ACL allow localhost
   ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Stream>

<Redirect index.html>    # Just an URL redirect for index
   # Redirect index.html to the appropriate site
   URL http://www.ffmpeg.org/
</Redirect>
```

and when I run the server with that config file, I get the following errors:

```
ffserver version 2.6.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
ffserver.conf:1: Port option is deprecated. Use HTTPPort instead.
ffserver.conf:2: BindAddress option is deprecated. Use HTTPBindAddress instead.
ffserver.conf:8: NoDaemon option has no effect. You should remove it.
ffserver.conf:13: ACL refers to invalid host or IP address '#'
ffserver.conf:26: Invalid codec name: 'libvpx'
ffserver.conf:31: Option not found: 'cpu-used'
ffserver.conf:31: If 'cpu-used' is a codec privateoption, then prefix it with codec name, for example 'vp8:cpu-used 0' or define codec earlier.
ffserver.conf:34: Option not found: 'quality'
ffserver.conf:39: Setting default value for audio sample rate = 22050. Use NoDefaults to disable it.
ffserver.conf:39: Setting default value for audio channel count = 1. Use NoDefaults to disable it.
```

How can I run it successfuly? I want to stream live webm video, but so far I stuck at the point of starting ffserver..

Comment: What's the destribution? What are the ffmpeg config options? Is libvpx installed?

Comment: I try to run the ffserver on OSX Yosemite, I'm not sure yet how the check the ffmpeg config options though... I think I don't have the libvpx installed - can I just add it to the existing installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ffmpeg lists config options on any invocation, and there's no `--enable-libvpx` option in your configuration. Try building ffmpeg with `--enable-libvpx`.

Comment: Hey, sorry if that's stupid question, but could you give me a hint how to rebuild the package with this option? I tried to look for this information here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos but that was not helpful.. Thanks

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX is probably what you need, considering that you run OSX.